# Get a variable of python function

Tags: python, function, variables, tkinter, messagebox

I started in python, so please excuse me if the vocabulary I use is unsuitable. I created a function and I would like recover the place where the file is located (its URL into the computer) in a variable.

Does anybody can tell me how is that possible?

Thank you in advance

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.messagebox import*
import tkinter.filedialog

Tk().withdraw()

def insert_photo():
    photo = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Ouvrir une image",filetypes=[('Jpg files','.jpg'),('Gif files','.gif'),('Bmp files','.bmp'),('Png files','.png'),('Tiff files','.tif'),('All files','.*')])
    return photo
```

Actually, I just want to get a variable in the path of the image file so that I could call it more easily in another script.

I have tried `print(os.path.realpath(__file__))` but the problem is that even when tkinter window lance. I just wish that the function is executed in the shell and only when I called it, exploring window opens and I can get the path in a variable.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about which "file" you're referring to, and what problem you're having saving it to a variable. If it's the image file that you're prompting the user for, that's returned by your function, and the calling code can assign it to a variable if you want. If you want the file your code is in, then something like what you have with `__file__` should work with an assignment instead of the `print` call.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what your problem is. I have run your code and it works. Are you after a UNC path?

Have you tried:

```
>>> p = insert_photo():
>>> print(p)
```

You seem to have your path already.

If you are trying to open the file dialog in a specific folder you can change the current working directory with `os.chdir(PATH)`.

If you only want the folder the image is in you can do `os.path.split(PATH)[0]`

Comment: Yes it works very well, but the problem is that when I directly run the script, the window also opens when I just want to be able to call the function when I want without the window opens at the early; and recover the variable once the window opens.